# If I have an $n$-gon, for odd $n\geq5$ with all angles equal to the angles of the regular $n$-gon, is my $n$-gon necessarily regular?

Tags: geometry

To paraphrase the title, is there such thing as an odd-sided (with at least 5 equal sides) non-regular polygon with all equal interior angles?

So for example, if I have a pentagon with all angles being $108^\circ$, then is it necessarily a regular pentagon?

I have constructed an example that I think works, but I just want to be sure.

The example I constructed is below, where you cut the red strip away from the regular pentagon and glue the halves together. The mid-line of the strip is concurrent to the line connecting the vertex to the mid-point of the opposite side.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I have just added conditions on $n$ to avoid that, as I forgot to do so initially.

Comment: What example did you construct?

Comment: hexagons can have external angles all $60$ degrees but different side lengths.

Comment: I observed that the result was trivial for even $n$, which was why I had $n$ being odd in the title.

Comment: I think your example is a good one.

Comment: Are there any other such constructions (of an example/counter example), or is this the only one?

Comment: Your construction is fine, but one can do more: translating any side of the $n$-gon parallel to itself does not change the angles.

Comment: Are you sure about that one @Aretino? If you drag the base side of the pentagon to the side, would that not change some of the angles? I can imagine if I drag it far to the right, it would even make one of the angles acute!

Comment: I mean: you can translate any line to which a side belongs, along a direction perpendicular to it, and the $n$-gon formed by the translated lines will have the same angles as before.

Comment: I'm not quite following unfortunately. If you have a quick diagram and attach it as an answer, I'd be happy to tick it off.

Comment: It's basically this one: https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/parallel-lines.html (same corresponding angles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of what I wrote in the above comment.

[image]

Comment: Would never have thought of this. I think this is a much better counter example than my one, which I felt was 'cheat'-ish.